# How to export a generic MATLAB matrix to a text file, formatted like C# array

Tags: c#, matlab, export

I have a matrix in MATLAB, like this:

```
[ 1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12]
```

I want to export it to a text file, in C# format:

```
double[,] myMat = { {1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12} };
```

I need a MATLAB function, called for example `exportMatrix()`, with two arguments:

- the MATLAB matrix
- the tipo in which this matrix must be exported

Two examples of how to use this function are the following:

```
exportMatrix( myMatrix1, 'short');
exportMatrix( myMatrix2, 'float');
```

I need also that if the matrix is multidimensional, the function should export it correctly. For example, if:

```
>> size(A)

ans =

        100        10           3
```

then the result of calling  `exportMatrix( A, 'double');` should be:

```
double[, ,] A = {...};
```

Comment: You can use [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) to format the output correctly. ([more info](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/import_export/writing-to-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a fun question :) Here is a starting point:

```
function exportMatrix(A)
% get dimensions 
dimensions  = size(A);
N_dim       = length(dimensions);

% print variable declaration to console
fprintf('double[')
for i = 1:N_dim-1
    fprintf(',')
end
% finish declaration and print rows of matrix
fprintf('] A= {%s}\n', exportRow(A, dimensions))

function str_out = exportRow(B, dims)
% recursively print matrix

% init output string
str_out = '';

% have we finished yet?
if length(dims) > 1
    % if not, then go to next layer
    for i=1:dims(1)
        % this test is just to make sure that we do not reshape a
        % one-dimensional array
        if length(dims) > 2
            % print next slice inside curly-braces
            str_out = sprintf('%s{ %s },', str_out, exportRow(reshape(B(i,:), dims(2:end)), dims(2:end)) );
        elseif length(dims) == 2
            % we are almost at the end, so do not use reshape, but stil
            % print in curly braces
            str_out = sprintf('%s{ %s },', str_out, exportRow(B(i,:), dims(2:end)) );
        end
    end
else
    % we have found one of the final layers, so print numbers
    str_out = sprintf('%f, ', B);
    % strip last space and comma
    str_out = str_out(1:end-2);
end
% strip final comma and return
str_out = sprintf('%s', str_out(1:end-1));
```

which only works for 2D arrays and upwards. Try eg.

```
exportMatrix(rand(2,2,2))
```

you need to alter the fprintf statements if you want to print to a file...

Comment: It's a good starting point. You can also modify the above function with another input that represents the type of the matrix in C#